# why am i not getting the data from Rapidapi

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit, rapidapi

i want to use  rapidapi to get some data using redux, but when i console.log the data i will be getting GET https://coinranking1.p.rapidapi.com/coins/coins 401 (Unauthorized). please what am i doing wrong, someone help me out

here is my code on my store.js file

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit"
import {cryptoApi} from "../services/cryptoApi"

export default configureStore({
    reducer: {
         [cryptoApi.reducerPath]: cryptoApi.reducer,
    },
})
```

here is where i store the data am getting from rapidapi

```
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery} from "@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react"

const cryptoApiHeaders = {
    'X-RapidAPI-Host': 'coinranking1.p.rapidapi.com',
    'X-RapidAPI-Key': my-key
}

const baseUrl = 'https://coinranking1.p.rapidapi.com/coins'
const createRequest = (url) => ({url, Headers: cryptoApiHeaders })

export const cryptoApi = createApi({
    ReducerPath: "cryptoApi",
    baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery( { baseUrl } ),
    endpoints: (builder) => ({
        getCryptos: builder.query({
            query: () => createRequest("/exchanges")
        })
    })
})

export const { useGetCryptosQuery, } = cryptoApi;


import { useGetCryptosQuery } from "../services/cryptoApi"

    const {data, isFetching } = useGetCryptosQuery();
    console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
const baseUrl = 'https://coinranking1.p.rapidapi.com/coins'
```

Try changing like this:

```
const baseUrl = 'https://coinranking1.p.rapidapi.com'
```

Also add **coins** or **exchanges** according to the data you need.

if you need data from **exchanges** add this:

```
query: () => createRequest("/exchanges")
```

or if you need **coins** data change like this:

```
query: () => createRequest("/coins")
```